# Selecting a class with CSS

Tags: html, css

Here is a portion of the html I'm looking to edit in a css. To my understanding, I just need to use #coupon to edit the coupon div's. However, it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="coupon">
   <h1>Classic Combo</h1>
   <p>16" 1-Topping Pizza
      &amp; a 2-Liter of Your Choice
      For Only $14.99
   </p>
   <p>Expires 3/14</p>
</div>
<div class="coupon">
   <h1>Pizza &amp; Stix</h1>
   <p>16" Specialty Pizza
      Reg. Cheese Stix &amp; a 2-Liter
      For Only $21.99
   </p>
```

Comment: how does you CSS code look?

Comment: An oldie but a goodie - [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.coupon`, not `#coupon`

In CSS, `.` denotes a class name, while `#` denotes an element's id

Comment: No prob.  I see you're really new here, so just FYI, if someone's correctly answered your question you should accept the answer, not/in addition to upvoting it.

Comment: [Relevant Meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in) for you @BIU :)

Answer (score 0):

USe this in css

```
.coupon{
    // write your style here
}
```

In css `# = id` and `. = class`

Answer (score 0):

The `#coupon` selector is used for id elements.  Try using `.coupon`.  That should fix your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

in your Html when you use `id='something'` then in referring to this element with css you should use `#` before the id. Ids must be unique in html.it means that you should not have 2 tags or more having the same id. in this case you should use `class='something'` and for referring in css you use `.` before it's class name,and everything having that class takes css.

and here you have class in your html.so you should use `.coupon` not `#coupon` as others says.

and one other thing is ids have priority over classes.it means that if you have

```
<div id="greenColor" class="redColor"></div>
```

and in your css you have

```
#greenColor{
 color: green;
}

.redColor{
 color: red;
}
```

your text in div will get `color: green` css over `color: red` css.